# How to use AngualarJs ng-grid or ui-calendar with popover

Tags: angularjs, popover

Actually I want to create a calendar like Google calendar, In which user can able to create events. So that I want a popover when user clicks on cells. Please give me any suggestion for this. I have also confused between ng-grid and ui-calendar, which is the best option for drawing calendar, binding click event etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No reason to worry about ng-grid, you could build a calendar out of it but the existence of ui-calendar makes that just a good coding/css exercise.

The Angular UI Calendar (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar) is a wrapper around the jQuery fullcalendar plugin (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/). You can use the documentation on the latter and pass options right through the directive.

Example from the GitHub page referenced above:

```
myAppModule.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    /* config object */
    $scope.calendarConfig = {
        height: 450,
        editiable: true,
        dayClick: function(){
            scope.$apply($scope.alertEventOnClick);
        }
    };
});

<div ui-calendar="calendarOptions" ng-model="eventSources">
```

Comment: Thanks for reply... but how to open popover when clicking on calendar cells.

Comment: The plugin is extremely well documented: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/

Comment: ya... Its great plugin and its fulfilling my all requirements but it is possible to create same type of module with Angularjs using ng-grid or ui-calendar ??